# Using minidom to break down an xml file into managable files. Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, minidom

I am currently trying to use python to create 3 files from one xml file.

There are three types of data in the xml file, estates, symbol names and tick types.

I want 3 text files, listing the 3 different things.

This is currently my code, and it lists the estates absolutely fine:

```
    from xml.dom import minidom


#Define the xmldoc object
xmldoc = minidom.parse('C:\\Temp\\Symbols.xml')

#Define EstateList by getting Elements by tag name
EstateList = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('Estate')
#Print Estate List
print "There are currently %d data estates" % len(EstateList)
#print EstateList[0].attributes['EstateName'].value
for s in EstateList:
    print s.attributes['EstateName'].value

#Save Estate List to file
with open('dataestates.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write("There are currently %d data estates \n" % len(EstateList))
    for s in EstateList:
        f.write(s.attributes['EstateName'].value + "\n")
```

However, when I start looking at the other ones, symbol names and tick types I can't get anything to work, I can't get close to it listing tick types, I've tried attributes, tags, all sorts.

Here is an example of the xml code

```
   <Estates>
     <Estate EstateName="BBG.DL.BOND.RAW._LIVE">
       <Ticktype>BBG_BGN</Ticktype>
       <Ticktype>BBG_BVAL</Ticktype>
       <Ticktype>BBG_CBBT</Ticktype>
       <Ticktype>BBG_IXEP</Ticktype>
       <Ticktype>BBG_IXSP</Ticktype>
       <Ticktype>BBG_TRAC</Ticktype>
       <Ticktype>BBG</Ticktype>
     </Estate>
     <Estate EstateName="BBG.DL.CCY.RAW._LIVE">
       <Ticktype>BBG</Ticktype>
     </Estate>
</Estates>
<Symbols>
     <Symbol SymbolName="AT0000386073 Corp" Estate="BBG.DL.BOND.RAW._LIVE" TickType="BBG_BGN" />
     <Symbol SymbolName="AT0000386073 Corp" Estate="BBG.DL.BOND.RAW._LIVE" TickType="BBG_BVAL" />
</Symbols>
```

Comment: The subject line contains `etree` and you also set the _elementtree_ tag but the actual question uses `xml.minidom` instead‽

Comment: @BlackJack I noticed that myself. It's because I started writing this question when trying to do it with etree, then tried with xml.minidom and forgot to update the subject and tags. My mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1. Ticks

The interior text of a `<Ticktype>` element is stored in a child node. To access the text, you must find that child. [`Node.firstChild`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html#xml.dom.Node.firstChild) should do it for you. Once you have found the child node, you can get the text through the [`Text.data`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html#xml.dom.Text.data) attribute.

Thus, given a `<Ticktype>` element, you can find the text as: `.firstChild.data`.

```
ticklist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('Ticktype')
print "There are currently %d tick types" % len(ticklist)
for s in ticklist:
    print s.firstChild.data
```

The tick types appear to have duplicate values. You can reduce them to a unique list by using a `set`:

```
tickset = set(s.firstChild.data for s in ticklist)
print "There are %d unique tick types" % len(tickset)
for s in tickset:
    print s
```

#### 2. Symbols

Symbols are stored nearly identically to how estates are. Thus, they are extracted similarly to how estates are extracted:

```
symlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('Symbol')
print "There are currently %d symbols" % len(symlist)
for s in symlist:
    print s.attributes['SymbolName'].value
```

Comment: This works fantastically, thank you, however I can't get it to work for the symbols. I use identical code just replacing names and file locations etc. and I get an error saying that there is no attribute called data for the content of <Symbol /> which I understand. What would I use instead of s.firstChild.data to return just the string after "SymbolName="

Comment: I've updated my answer to include information about `<Symbol/>`.